# iptables and multiple ipsets

Tags: firewall, iptables

I have multiple ipsets (nearly 300) that contain lists of IP addresses I would like to drop via iptables on my CentOS server running WHM/cPanel CSF/LFD.

How best to write the rule for this to work, and does a separate rule need to be written for each ipset (or can I use one rule)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This sounds more like a question for Server Fault or Network Engineering.

Comment: Really?  Sorry, I didn't know.  I will try other sites - thanks for info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, this question is more appropriate for Server Fault.

A quick note, assuming a set call "badguys" you could log and then DROP as follows (assuming they are treated as source addresses)

iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set badguys src -j LOG --log-prefix "badguys "

iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set badguys src -j DROP